# Outlook 2010 customize fields under instant search box

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2010

On my computer, when I click into the search box in Microsoft Outlook 2010, a list of specific search fields appear below (like "from" or "to").

[image: screenshot]

I would like to add some other frequently used fields here, but can't find where this is configured or what it's called.

I have a vague suspicion that I configured this in Outlook 2007 but after upgrading it's left as-is and I don't know!  Is it even possible to configure it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found out answer myself. On search toolbar in ribbon there is "More" button which allows adding those fields.

[image: Highlited button]

Hope that this will help other lost souls out there.